# Keras DQN: Why does it complain about shape of a dictionary observation space?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning, tf.keras, openai-gym, sequential

I have used Custom gym Env and pip installed it.

The custom gym env has a function def model as below:

```
def dqn_model(self):
    self.flat_obs = gym.spaces.utils.flatten_space(self.observation_space)
    # self.flat_obs = (10945,)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,) + (self.flat_obs.shape[0],)))

    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    model.add(Dense(32, name="Hidden_layer_1"))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    
    model.add(Dense(self.action_space.n, name="Output_Layer"))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE))

    logger.info(model.summary())
    return model
```

I import this in the DQN class and build a model as so :

`model = env.dqn_model()` : which builds a model as so.

```
[wingman_env.py -            dqn_model:210] : Flattened shape : Box(0.0, [12.  1.  1. ...  1.  1.  1.], (10945,), float64) 
[wingman_env.py -            dqn_model:211] : Flattened shape : (10945,) 
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 10945)             0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 64)                700544    
                                                                 
 activation (Activation)     (None, 64)                0         
                                                                 
 Hidden_layer_1 (Dense)      (None, 32)                2080      
                                                                 
 activation_1 (Activation)   (None, 32)                0         
                                                                 
 Output_Layer (Dense)        (None, 21)                693       
                                                                 
 activation_2 (Activation)   (None, 21)                0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 703,317
Trainable params: 703,317
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
[wingman_env.py -            dqn_model:232] : None
```

Now when i run the below function, no matter what I do, it keeps complaining about the dimension as so:

```
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=15000, log_interval=1000, visualize=False)

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1)
```

I have seen other questions on the forum but none of them solve my problem. I have tried many things as stated above but always fail to identify where this error is coming from. Happy to see one of you help me here.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to it.

It was complaining due to below reason.

1. The model was built to take in (None, flattened_observation_space). In my case, it was a dictionary observation space. Flattened dimension was 513.
2. The DQN model was always receiving 1D array (ie, the very first element of the dictionary)
3. It never occurred to me that Keras DQN would also need to process my dictionary space as per the model. Hence, on realizing the same, I wrote a MyProcessor class that uses the same flattening method and batching method that was used to build the model.

Sample code:

```
class MyProcessor(Processor):
    def process_observation(self, observation):
        print(f"Received data in flatten obs : {len(observation)}")
        flat_observation = []
        for elem in observation['param_2']:
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_1']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_2']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_3']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_4']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_5']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_6']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_7']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_8']))
                
        flat_observation.append(observation['param_3'])
        return np.reshape(flat_observation, (-1, np.array(flat_observation).size))
    
    def process_state_batch(self, batch):
        # Transpose the batch of arrays to match the input shape of the network
        try:
            processed_batch = batch.reshape((513, 1)).transpose()
        except:
            processed_batch = np.squeeze(np.concatenate(batch, axis=1))
        print(f"Batch size is : {processed_batch.size}")
        return processed_batch
```

And tada : It worked like a charm!